# $_SESSION занести время и передать ее в переменной в другой php

Tags: php, javascript, сессия, jquery-file-upload

Использую jQuery-File-Upload при загрузке файлов создаю папку на сервере и заливаю туда.

```
 $folder = date("d-m-Y H-i-s"); // присваиваем переменно сег. дату
    $up = '/image/'.$folder.'/';
    //$title = '/4ddddd/';
        $this->response = array();
        $this->options = array(
            'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.$this->basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')),
            'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).$up,
            'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().$up,
```

Переменную `$up` нужно продлить жизнь пока пользователь на сайте... Думаю через `$_SESSION` как реализовать не знаю....

Comment: У вас пользователи как то авторизируются?) Если да то там где храните даные об авторизации пользователя там же можете и хранить даные о названии папки. Например те же куки если хотите, ну или если хотите чтото в сесию записать `$_SESSION['name'] = "value";`

Comment: Не авторизуются не как ...

Comment: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php

Answer (score 2):

Сделать

```
<?php
session_start(); // Точку с запятой добавил
```

**в начале скрипта**.

Далее в рассматриваемом блоке:

```
$folder = date("d-m-Y H-i-s"); // присваиваем переменно сег. дату
// Начало изменённого кода
if(!isset($_SESSION['up'])){
    $_SESSION['up'] = '/image/'.$folder.'/';
}
$up = $_SESSION['up'];
// Конец изменённого кода
//$title = '/4ddddd/';
 $this->response = array();
        $this->options = array(
            'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.$this->basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')),
            'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).$up,
            'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().$up,
```

Comment: Будем пробовать

Comment: session_start() куда ставить? тут php код

Comment: @ЭрикГалин, а `session_start()` разве не является функцией php, что ее поставить в php код нельзя?

Comment: выдает ошибку при загрузке вот в чем то дело

Comment: _session_start() куда ставить?_ - сразу после `<?php`

Comment: _выдает ошибку при загрузке вот в чем то дело_ - Проверьте точку с запятой. Добавил комментарии в ответ.

Comment: session_start() должен идти до любой отправки данных на клиент.

Comment: @ЭрикГалин, кодировка файла должна быть UTF-8 без BOM.